# Is MongoDB C# Driver's ObjectID implementation guaranteed unique?

Tags: mongodb, uniqueidentifier, mongodb-.net-driver

It's shorter than GUID (96 bit vs 128 bit), so I was wondering if it's as reliably unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are a finite number of ObjectIds they are not absolutely guaranteed to be unique. However, the chances of a collision are exceedingly small. The C# driver's implementation of ObjectId is no different from that of any other driver or of the MongoDB server itself.

Answer (score 0):

> #### BSON ObjectID Specification
>
> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value consisting of a 4-byte timestamp (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

C# and GUID has nothing to do with ObjectID and looks like it is guaranteed to be unique based on this description.